# Nextjs api not working on vercel version 18

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I have created this simple api when the page loads:

```
const GetResponse = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/createAcc/check", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify("hello"),
      });
      if (!res.ok) {
        const errorMessage = await res.json();
        console.error("Error if:", errorMessage.error);
        return;
      }
    };
```

and here is the recieving end:

```
export default async function Check(req, res) {
  try {
    res.json({ message: "Success" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
}
```

but the server respons with error. It works locally but crashes on vercel.